# Reverse geocoding returning null suddenly after few days in android

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I am developing an app in android in which user get their address from reverse geocoding. I made it and it was working fine until 3 days ago but now it is not returning any address.

MainAtivity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

private static final String ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY = "address-request-pending";
private static final String LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY = "location-address";

/**
 * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
 */
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

/**
 * Represents a geographical location.
 */
private Location mLastLocation;

/**
 * Tracks whether the user has requested an address. Becomes true when the user requests an
 * address and false when the address (or an error message) is delivered.
 */
private boolean mAddressRequested;

/**
 * The formatted location address.
 */
private String mAddressOutput;

/**
 * Receiver registered with this activity to get the response from FetchAddressIntentService.
 */
private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;

/**
 * Displays the location address.
 */

private TextView selectManually;
private TextView mLocationAddressTextView;

/**
 * Visible while the address is being fetched.
 */
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

/**
 * Kicks off the request to fetch an address when pressed.
 */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_fetch);

    mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar2);
    selectManually= findViewById(R.id.select_manually);

    // Set defaults, then update using values stored in the Bundle.
    mAddressRequested = false;
    mAddressOutput = "";
    updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions();
    } else {
        getAddress();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    updateUIWidgets();
}



/**
 * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
 */
private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Check savedInstanceState to see if the address was previously requested.
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY)) {
            mAddressRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY);
        }
        // Check savedInstanceState to see if the location address string was previously found
        // and stored in the Bundle. If it was found, display the address string in the UI.
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY)) {
            mAddressOutput = savedInstanceState.getString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocationShow.class);
            intent.putExtra("addressOutput", mAddressOutput);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Runs when user clicks the Fetch Address button.

/**
 * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
 * fetching an address.
 */
private void startIntentService() {
    // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

    // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

    // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLastLocation);

    // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
    // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
    // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
    startService(intent);
}

/**
 * Gets the address for the last known location.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void getAddress() {
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onSuccess:null");
                        mAddressRequested=false;
                        updateUIWidgets();
                        return;
                    }

                    mLastLocation = location;

                    // Determine whether a Geocoder is available.
                    if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                        showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_geocoder_available));
                        mAddressRequested=false;
                        updateUIWidgets();
                        return;
                    }

                    // If the user pressed the fetch address button before we had the location,
                    // this will be set to true indicating that we should kick off the intent
                    // service after fetching the location.
                    mAddressRequested=true;
                    if (mAddressRequested) {
                        startIntentService();
                        return;
                    }
                    updateUIWidgets();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:onFailure", e);
                    mAddressRequested=false;
                    updateUIWidgets();
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Updates the address in the UI.
 */

/**
 * Toggles the visibility of the progress bar. Enables or disables the Fetch Address button.
 */
private void updateUIWidgets() {
    mAddressRequested=true;
    if (mAddressRequested) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        selectManually.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    } else {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        selectManually.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows a toast with the given text.
 */
private void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save whether the address has been requested.
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY, mAddressRequested);

    // Save the address string.
    savedInstanceState.putString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY, mAddressOutput);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
 */
private class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    /**
     * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
        mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocationShow.class);
        intent.putExtra("addressOutput", mAddressOutput);
        startActivity(intent);

        // Show a toast message if an address was found.
        if (resultCode == Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
            showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));

        }

        // Reset. Enable the Fetch Address button and stop showing the progress bar.

    }
}

/**
 * Shows a {@link Snackbar} using {@code text}.
 *
 * @param text The Snackbar text.
 */
private void showSnackbar(final String text) {
    View container = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if (container != null) {
        Snackbar.make(container, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Shows a {@link Snackbar}.
 *
 * @param mainTextStringId The id for the string resource for the Snackbar text.
 * @param actionStringId   The text of the action item.
 * @param listener         The listener associated with the Snackbar action.
 */
private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                          View.OnClickListener listener) {
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            getString(mainTextStringId),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
}

/**
 * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
    // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

        showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Request permission
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                });

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
        // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
        // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted.
            getAddress();
        } else {
            // Permission denied.

            // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
            // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
            // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

            // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
            // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
            // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
            // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
            // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(
                                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

}

FetchAddressIntentService

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "FetchAddressIS";

/**
 * The receiver where results are forwarded from this service.
 */
private ResultReceiver mReceiver;

/**
 * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
 * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
 */
public FetchAddressIntentService() {
    // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
    super(TAG);
}

/**
 * Tries to get the location address using a Geocoder. If successful, sends an address to a
 * result receiver. If unsuccessful, sends an error message instead.
 * Note: We define a {@link ResultReceiver} in * MainActivity to process content
 * sent from this service.
 *
 * This service calls this method from the default worker thread with the intent that started
 * the service. When this method returns, the service automatically stops.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String errorMessage = "";

    mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);

    // Check if receiver was properly registered.
    if (mReceiver == null) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "No receiver received. There is nowhere to send the results.");
        return;
    }

    // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
    Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

    // Make sure that the location data was really sent over through an extra. If it wasn't,
    // send an error error message and return.
    if (location == null) {
        errorMessage = "no location data provided";
        Log.wtf(TAG, errorMessage);
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Errors could still arise from using the Geocoder (for example, if there is no
    // connectivity, or if the Geocoder is given illegal location data). Or, the Geocoder may
    // simply not have an address for a location. In all these cases, we communicate with the
    // receiver using a resultCode indicating failure. If an address is found, we use a
    // resultCode indicating success.

    // The Geocoder used in this sample. The Geocoder's responses are localized for the given
    // Locale, which represents a specific geographical or linguistic region. Locales are used
    // to alter the presentation of information such as numbers or dates to suit the conventions
    // in the region they describe.
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    // Address found using the Geocoder.
    List<Address> addresses = null;

    try {
        // Using getFromLocation() returns an array of Addresses for the area immediately
        // surroungetString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used)ding the given latitude and longitude. The results are a best guess and are
        // not guaranteed to be accurate.
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(),
                // In this sample, we get just a single address.
                1);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // Catch network or other I/O problems.
        errorMessage = "service not available";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
        errorMessage ="invalid lat and  long" ;
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
    }

    // Handle case where no address was found.
    if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
        if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMessage = "no address found";
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
    } else {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<>();

        // Fetch the address lines using {@code getAddressLine},
        // join them, and send them to the thread. The {@link android.location.address}
        // class provides other options for fetching address details that you may prefer
        // to use. Here are some examples:
        // getLocality() ("Mountain View", for example)
        // getAdminArea() ("CA", for example)
        // getPostalCode() ("94043", for example)
        // getCountryCode() ("US", for example)
        // getCountryName() ("United States", for example)
        for(int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            addressFragments.add(address.getSubLocality());
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "address found");
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments));
    }
}

/**
 * Sends a resultCode and message to the receiver.
 */
private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
    mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
}
```

}

LocationShow

```
public class LocationShow extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView t1;
String output,output2;
private static final String ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY = "address-request-pending";
private static final String LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY = "location-address";
String mAddressOutput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1=findViewById(R.id.place2);

    output = getIntent().getStringExtra("addressOutput");
    output2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("addressOutput2");

    showAddress(output2);
}

private void showAddress(String place) {

    t1.setText(place);
}
```

}

Constants

```
final class Constants {
static final int SUCCESS_RESULT = 0;

static final int FAILURE_RESULT = 1;

private static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
        "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationaddress";

static final String RECEIVER = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RECEIVER";

static final String RESULT_DATA_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RESULT_DATA_KEY";

static final String LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA = PACKAGE_NAME + ".LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA";
```

}

This is the log output

```
07-16 23:36:43.553 16544-16544/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

07-16 23:36:43.948 16555-16555/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-16 23:36:43.948 16555-16555/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-16 23:36:44.440 16566-16566/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-16 23:36:44.440 16566-16566/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-16 23:36:44.935 16577-16577/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-16 23:36:44.935 16577-16577/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-16 23:36:45.641 16588-16588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-16 23:36:45.641 16588-16588/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-16 23:36:46.052 16599-16599/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-16 23:36:46.052 16599-16599/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-16 23:36:46.241 16608-16612/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
07-16 23:36:46.772 1322-1322/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1055021888.tmp: No such file or directory
07-16 23:36:46.952 1990-13324/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
07-16 23:36:47.363 16660-16660/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-16 23:36:47.363 16660-16660/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-16 23:36:47.682 2016-2281/com.android.launcher3 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f4388d4cc80
07-16 23:36:47.724 16699-16699/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:47.936 16717-16717/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:47.995 16722-16722/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.044 16725-16725/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.079 16728-16728/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.122 16732-16732/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.149 16736-16736/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.185 16739-16739/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.219 16743-16743/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.249 16629-16729/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.partnersetup.rlzappprovider
07-16 23:36:48.259 16746-16746/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.299 16750-16750/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.user.practice-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
07-16 23:36:48.817 1226-1269/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

These are the activities which i am using to show current user location in the application. The activities were working fine before but now only progressbar is showing and nothing else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Google just made some big changes to its mapping APIs.  Without log output of some sort it's hard to say what might be happening, but if you made no code changes, I would check your account associated with your mapping key and see if you need to add a credit card to the account.  More info here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates

Comment: I enabled the billing and also got free credits just like the API rules but still no result